# iOS app not loading all data from Parse.com asyncronously in the correct order

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm new to iOS development and I am stuck on an issue. I am implementing a Tinder like swipe functionality for an application using code from https://github.com/cwRichardKim/TinderSimpleSwipeCards

Here is the code I have that is giving me trouble.

```
imageCard = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (objects != nil) {
            NSMutableArray *imageDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                // add all image objects into imagesArray
                [imageDataArray addObject:object[@"content"]];
            }
            // loop through imageDataArray and get each image
            for (int i = 0; i < [imageDataArray count]; i++) {
                PFFile *imageFile = imageDataArray[i];
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        NSLog(@"loop: %d",i);
                        [imageCard addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                        // ***** only loadCards after all images have been retrieved
                        if (i == [imageDataArray count] - 1) {
                            loadedCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                            allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                            cardsLoadedIndex = 0;
                            NSLog(@"Cards loaded");
                            [self loadCards];
                        }
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
```

So I'm querying Parse for all images in the Post table. I then put all of the image data in the imagesArray. Then I loop though the imagesArray and get the actual images from the image data in a background thread and put the actual image into another array (imageCard). Once all images are added to imageCard then I want to loadCards([self loadCards]).

Let's say imageDataArray has 6 objects. Now the issue is that getDataInBackgroundWithBlock asynchronously running 6 times. I Only want to [self loadCards] when the last object is loaded, but the last object could be loaded before other objects. Here is a console output of the issue for a visual.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvI83.jpg

As you can see, the data isn't loaded in ascending order, it's loaded randomly, and anything after "Cards loaded" is not loaded and that's the issue i need help with.

Thanks!

Comment: You can sort queries multiple ways...one of which is `orderByAscending` which I think is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem, is as you noted, that asynchronous tasks will complete in an undefined order.  Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) has a solution for [waiting for a number of asynchronous tasks to complete](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25) using a dispatch group.

To use it, you need to replace the asynchronous Parse method `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` with the synchronous version `getData` and  dispatch the task into an asynchronous queue yourself-

```
imageCard = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (objects != nil) {
        NSMutableArray *imageDataArray = [object valueForKey:@"content];

        dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
        dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

            // loop through imageDataArray and get each image

        for (PFFile *imageFile in imageDataArray) {
            dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
                NSData *data=[imageFile getData] 
                if (data!=nil) {
                    NSLog(@"loop: %d",i);
                    [imageCard addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
                }
            });
         }
// When you cannot make any more forward progress,
// wait on the group to block the current thread.
         dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// Release the group when it is no longer needed.
         dispatch_release(group);

         loadedCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         allCards = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         cardsLoadedIndex = 0;
         NSLog(@"Cards loaded");
         [self loadCards];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Hi Paul! So your solution worked! Thanks!! Although sometimes when i run the app, i get this error "malloc: *** error for object 0x7f868a020a20: double free
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

Also, how can I have the asynchronous tasks load in the order i want them to.. i.e 1 - 6. Currently they load in a random order. Sometimes 6 is loading first.

Comment: The crash could be caused by a non-thread safe access to the mutable array - you could use an @synchronised block when you add the image. The only way you will get the images to load in order to not load them asynchronously and in parallel. You can dispatch the whole for loop asynchronously but still use the synchronous getData call - this will take longer to fetch the data